Angular - NGRx - Signal Store - do I need to unsubscribe from Reactive Methods?
I have a ngRx signal store, it is a global singleton
Global Store
(doesn't get destroyed when component is destroyed)
export const Store = signalStore(
  {providedIn: 'root'},

  withState(initialState),

  withMethods((store) => {

    const apiService = inject(APIService);

    return {
      loadObjectByID: rxMethod<string>(
        pipe(
          filter(id => id !== undefined),
          tap(() => patchState(store, { isLoading: true, isLoaded: false })),
          take(1),
          switchMap((id) => {
            return apiService.getObject(id).pipe(
              tap({
                next: (object) => patchState(store, { object }),
                finalize: () => {
                  patchState(store, { isLoading: false, isLoaded: true });
                }
              })
            );
          })
        )
      )
    }
  })
);

Then in a component, I do the following:
Component
  protected store = inject(Store)
  protected ngOnInit(): void {
      this.Store.loadObjectByID(this.objectID) --> only method available on this is '.unsubscribe'
  }

The documentation says "By default, the rxMethod needs to be executed within an injection context. It's tied to its lifecycle and is automatically cleaned up when the injector is destroyed."
What does this mean? What is the injection context in this instance? This part of the component,  protected store = inject(Store)? Ir this part of the store,   {providedIn: 'root'}?
Does the observable created by this.Store.loadObjectByID(this.objectID), in the component need to be unsubscribed manually (when it calls the reactive method, in the store), or will it be unsubscribed automatically when the component is destroyed?
Or will it persist, since the service is a global one, that only gets destroyed on a full app refresh?
Thanks in advance.


The global store will be destroy at the end of the application(you configured it as a singleton).
According to the docs - you need to run the rxMethod in an injection context in order to let angular handle the unsubscribe.
ngOnInit is not in the injection context


You have 2 solutions:

Unsubscribe manually.
rxMethod accepts an options as second param,you can supply an injector to preserve the behaviour outside of the injection context - keep in mind that is less recommended approach.

@
@Component({ /* ... */ })

    export class NumbersComponent implements OnInit {
      readonly #injector = inject(Injector);
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        const logNumber = rxMethod<number>(
          tap(console.log),
          { injector: this.#injector }
        );
    
        logNumber(10);
      }
    }
    
      
    
   

